# Strange Unit-Test behaviour in angular-cli generated application

Tags: unit-testing, angular, typescript, angular-cli

I created an application with angular-cli (latest version version 1.0.0-beta.25.5) and added a simple service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Headers, Http} from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
import {Todo} from './todo';

@Injectable()
export class TodoService {
  public todoUrl = 'http://localhost:4200/app/todos';  // URL to web api

  constructor(public http: Http) {
  }

  getTodos(): Promise<Todo[]> {
    return this.http.get(this.todoUrl)
      .toPromise()
      .then(response => response.json().data as Todo[])
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }

  handleError(error: any): Promise<any> {
    return Promise.reject(error.message || error);
  }
}
```

with a test for it:

```
import {TestBed, inject} from '@angular/core/testing';
import { TodoService } from './todo.service';
import {Todo} from './todo';
import {BaseRequestOptions, Http} from '@angular/http';
import {MockBackendService} from './mock-backend.service';
import {MockBackend} from '@angular/http/testing';

describe('TodoService', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [
        MockBackend,
        BaseRequestOptions,
        {
          provide: Http,
          deps: [MockBackend, BaseRequestOptions],
          useFactory: (backend: MockBackend, options: BaseRequestOptions) => {
            new MockBackendService().SetUpTodoBackend(backend);
            return new Http(backend, options);
          }
        },
        TodoService
      ]
    });
  });

  it('should return array of todos', inject([TodoService], (service: TodoService) => {
    service.getTodos().then((todos: Todo[]) => {
      console.log(todos.length);
      expect(todos.length).toEqual(100);
      expect(todos[0].id).toEqual(11);
      console.log('Finished.');
    });
  }));
});
```

In MockBackendService I return an array of 10 Todos, so the test should fail as it expects the array to contain 100 todos. When I run my test I get the following result:

```
LOG: 'mockConnection url:: http://localhost:4200/app/todos'
LOG: 10
LOG: 'Finished.'
Executed 1 of 1 SUCCESS (0.139 secs / 0.126 secs)
```

So it logs that the array contains 10 results but still passes the test. When I add 2 more "tests":

```
  it('should pass', () => {});
  it('should also pass', () => {});
```

the last test fails with the correct message from my first test:

```
TodoService should also pass FAILED
        Expected 10 to equal 100.
        @webpack:///src/app/todo.service.spec.ts:32:6 <- src/test.ts:70258:13 [ProxyZone]
        ProxyZoneSpec</ProxyZoneSpec.prototype.onInvoke@webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/proxy.js:79:0 <- src/test.ts:54312:20 [ProxyZone]
        Zone$1</Zone</Zone.prototype.run@webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/zone.js:113:0 <- src/test.ts:74539:24 [ProxyZone => ProxyZone]
        scheduleResolveOrReject/<@webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/zone.js:535:0 <- src/test.ts:74961:52 [ProxyZone]
        ProxyZoneSpec</ProxyZoneSpec.prototype.onInvokeTask@webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/proxy.js:103:0 <- src/test.ts:54336:20 [ProxyZone]
        Zone$1</ZoneDelegate</ZoneDelegate.prototype.invokeTask@webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/zone.js:274:0 <- src/test.ts:74700:21 [ProxyZone]
        Zone$1</Zone</Zone.prototype.runTask@webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/zone.js:151:0 <- src/test.ts:74577:28 [<root> => ProxyZone]
        drainMicroTaskQueue@webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/zone.js:433:0 <- src/test.ts:74859:25 [<root>]
Executed 3 of 3 (1 FAILED) (0.344 secs / 0.133 secs)
```

What am I doing wrong here to get such a strange behaviour? I can recreate that behaviour with a newly generated application, so it seems to be somewhere in my code or in a library I use...

Comment: The expectations are in a callback, have you tried using `done` to ensure the test doesn't finish before they're exercised?

Comment: Adding `done();` in the line after `console.log('Finished.');` changes nothing, still test 3 fails instead of test 1.

Comment: O.K., thanks, that was a hint in the right direction. I got it solved by getting the service in the beforeEach-Method and changing the test to: `it('should return array of todos', function(done) {` plus adding `done();` as described in my comment above. You can add your comment as an answer and I'll mark it as the correct one. Thanks a lot for your quick help!